# infinite while loop crashesTkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, pycharm

I was trying to make app that show you your mouse's coordinates live. I know in pyautogui has displayMousePosition() but it doesn't work somehow. (I use Pycharm)

```
from tkinter import *
from pyautogui import *
from time import * #I thought the sleep() command would help but didn't work :/
app = Tk()
ms_coor = str(position()) #I storaged the mouse position in a variable.
def update():
    while True:
        global ms_coor
        label1.config(text=ms_coor) #I wanted to update the label without creating a new label in next line.
button1 = Button(app, text="Start", command=update) #Starter button.
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label1 = Label(app, text="Please Start")
label1.grid(row=1, column=0)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: can't use a while loop like this, how do you expect the window to update? you have to think event-driven, use `after` to schedule the function to be called after some time instead of a while loop, plenty of resources online about after loops in tkinter

Comment: thanks bro I'll check out that sources

Answer (score 0):

Add `pyautogui.position()`.

Code snippet:

```
def update():
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
    
    label1.config(text=positionStr)
```